# inserting data to database doesnt work(PHP)

Tags: php, mysql

im trying to insert data into a db and I have no clue why its not working.

```
if(isset($_POST['reply_msg']))
{
    $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); 
    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT into pm
    (sent_to, sent_by, date, title, content, status)
    VALUES('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')"
    , $MSGInfo['sent_by']
    , $MSGInfo['sent_to']
    , $date
    , mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['reply_title'])
    , mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['reply_conent'])
    , 'Unread');

    if (!$sql){
        die('Sending failed ');
    }
    else echo 'Sent!';
}
```

table screenshot: http://prntscr.com/a2r47v

Comment: Did you create a connection? `$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);`

Comment: `mysql_query("INSERT into pm
                        (sent_to, sent_by, date, title, content, status)
                        VALUES('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')"
                        , $MSGInfo['sent_to']
                        , $MSGInfo['sent_by']
                        , $date
                        , mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['reply_title'])
                        , mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['reply_conent'])
                        , 'Unread' 
                        )` `sent_by` and `sent_to` got interchanged.

Comment: Yes, the code is just a part from a file, its just this part doesnt work.

Comment: why are you still using `mysql`? Use `mysqli` or PDO instead for security and ability reasons.

Comment: [`mysql_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) does not work like that. You can't do placeholders `%s` and then the values. It is like you are mixing `mysql_query()` with [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

Comment: @JimishGamit I know, its on purpose. I fixed the problem, thx anyway.

Comment: can you please post output of `describe pm`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should build your query PHP style, not C style. Even so, I would not recommend `mysql` for this, `mysqli` is better. Also, take a look at [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) for a higher level of security.

// setup query

```
$q = "INSERT INTO `pm` ('sent_to', 'sent_by', 'date', 'title', 'content', 'status')) VALUES(
$MSGInfo['sent_to'],$MSGInfo['sent_by'],$date,
mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['reply_title']), mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['reply_conent']),Unread)";
```

//Run Query

```
$result = mysql_query($q) or die(mysql_error());
```

Your query is not quite well built, you need to work a little more at it.